# flutter error: A problem occurred configuring project ':fluttertoast'

Tags: java, android, flutter, gradle, flutter-dependencies

today I was Working on my project suddenly my laptop gone hanged then I did my laptop restart,
then now I am trying to run my project again n again I am getting this error.
I dont know how to resolve this.(I have tried flutter clean and flutter pub cache clean)

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':fluttertoast'.
> Could not load compiled classes for build file 'C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\fluttertoast-8.2.2\android\build.gradle' from cache.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':fluttertoast' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
   > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':fluttertoast' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.20'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app/build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.flutter.pizzamenia"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.8.0"
}
```

pubspec.ymal

```
name: pizzamenia
description: A new Flutter application.

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.12.0 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter



  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.5
  pin_code_fields: ^7.4.0
  carousel_slider: ^4.2.1
  google_fonts: ^4.0.3
  fluttertoast: ^8.2.0
  dropdown_button2: ^1.9.3
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.2.3
  flutter_google_places: ^0.3.0
  dotted_border: ^2.0.0+3
  flutter_rating_bar: ^4.0.1
  flutter_bloc: ^8.1.2
  connectivity_plus: ^3.0.3
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.18
  dio: ^5.0.1
  skeletons: ^0.0.3
  geolocator: ^9.0.2
  geocoding: ^2.1.0
  sqflite: ^2.2.6
  path_provider: ^2.0.14
  intl: ^0.17.0
  paytm_allinonesdk: ^1.2.1
  webview_flutter: ^4.2.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.12.0
  package_info_plus: ^4.0.1

flutter_launcher_name:
  name: Rominus Pizza

#flutter_native_splash:
#  image: assets/splash.png
#  color: "ffffff"


flutter_icons:
  android: "ic_launcher"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/appLogo.jpg"

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/
    - assets/BannerImages/
    - assets/HomeMenu/


#  fonts:
#    - family: Poppins
#      fonts:
#        - asset: fonts/Poppins-Regular.ttf
#        - asset: fonts/Poppins-Medium.ttf
#          weight: 500
```

### Answer:

```
from distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip
to
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6.1-all.zip

and 

from: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.1'
to: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
```

Comment: Share your pubspec.yaml file code  for better understanding

Comment: @Prashant I have shared.

Comment: Peform flutter clean and then check the latest version of fluttertoast on pub.dev and update in pubspec.yaml then do perform flutter pub get

Comment: @Prashant I is not working